# Facebook login redirect iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

Good morning,

I would like to redirect to an another View (`MainViewController`) after the user is logged in using the Facebook login. I tried some code from Stackoverflow and other websites but they are not working in my project. Can you help me with that?

Here is my code from `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [FBLoginView class];
    return YES;
}
```

I'm not sure if that's the place where I have to edit in order to make the redirection. I have created a segue called `Main` which is the one I'm trying to use to make the redirection but it's still not working.

In my `ViewController.h`

```
@implementation aupViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];
    //self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
}

- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    //Here you segue your view controller
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Main" sender:self];
}

@end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you write this method `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{
    
    // Call FBAppCall's handleOpenURL:sourceApplication to handle Facebook app responses
    BOOL wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
    
    // You can add your app-specific url handling code here if needed
    
    return wasHandled;
}`

Comment: I copied your code and it's still not working. I have to change something? That's my first app, and I'm a little bit lost. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

See this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.1

There are FBLoginView delegate methods which is call after login sucessful.

```
// Logged-in user experience
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
   //Here you segue your view controller
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"youridentifier" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: That's the first thing I tried but it's still not working. I don't know why because it's pretty easy but it's not redirecting me to the MainViewController. Do you know why it's not working? Because the other redirects using the Segue worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry BHASKAR, but what do you mean? I will update my first message with some code. Thanks.